# Is it possible to programmatically define a Hierarchical Name in VHDL 2008?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim

I have a rather large project, comprised of many modules integrated into one top-level component. I've created test-benches for these modules which make use of API packages (which I've created alongside them). I also have a top-level test-bench that tests the integrated system as a whole.

For one of the components, I'm interested in using VHDL-2008 Hierarchical Names within its `MyModuleAPIPackage` in order to access the internal signals from the top level testbench. Since I'm trying to write modular and re-usable code, I'd like to be able to instantiate the package so that it references the signals of the module within the component-level test (where the module is at the top level)

```
<<signal .MyComponent.MySignal : std_logic>>
```

and also within the top-level test (where there is an underlying structure)

```
<<signal .MySystem.MySubSystem.MyComponent.MySignal : std_logic>>
```

Perhaps this could be attainable through a combination of Hierarchical Names and generics?

Here is some (pseudo) code exemplifying what I'm trying to achieve.

### MyModule.vhd

```
-- MyModule.vhd
entity MyModule is
  port(
    CLK : in std_logic;
    RST : in std_logic;

    DATA_IN : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    DATA_OUT : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
  );
end entity MyModule;

architecture behavioral of MyModule is
  -- Signal and constant definitions here.
begin
  -- Describes how MyModule behaves.
end architecture behavioral;

----------------------
-- MyModule Test-Bench
----------------------
entity MyModule_tb is
end entity MyModule_tb;

architecture test of MyModule_tb is
  -- Signal and constant definitions here
  signal CLK, RST : std_logic := '0';
  signal DATA_IN, DATA_OUT : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others = '0');

  procedure DoComplexStuff(
    InstructionCode : natural
  )
  is
  begin
    case InstructionCode is
      when 0 =>
        DATA_IN <= "01010101";
        wait until CLK = '1';
        DATA_IN <= "00110011";
        wait until CLK = '1';
        -- Lots of pretty complex stimuli
        assert DATA_OUT = "00110011"
        report "Output mismatch!"
        severity failure;
      when 1 =>
        -- Lots of pretty complex stimuli
      -- when ... =>
      -- Plenty more instruction codes
      others =>
        null;
  end procedure DoComplexStuff;  
begin
  CLK <= not CLK after 1 ms;

  MainTestProc:
  process
  begin
    for i in 0 to 99 loop
      DoComplexStuff(i);
    end loop;
  end;

  DUT: entity work.MyModule(behavioral)
    port map(
      CLK => CLK,
      RST => RST,
      DATA_IN => DATA_IN,
      DATA_OUT => DATA_OUT
    );
end architecture test;
```

I wish for `procedure DoComplexStuff` to be available at the top-level.

### MyModuleApi.vhd

```
package MyModuleAPI is
  generic(
  -- Programatically defined aliases
    PATH : path;
  )
  alias CLK is <<signal PATH.CLK : std_logic);
  alias RST is <<signal PATH.RST : std_logic);
  alias DATA_IN is <<signal PATH.DATA_IN : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
  alias DATA_OUTis <<signal PATH.DATA_OUT : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));

  procedure DoComplexStuff(
    InstructionCode : in natural
  );
end package;

package body MyModuleAPI is
  -- I can now include this package within MyModule_tb and
  -- MyTopLevelComponent_tb and call DoComplexStuff to interact with the signals
  -- from MyModule
  procedure DoComplexStuff(
    InstructionCode : natural
  )
  is
  begin
    case InstructionCode is
      when 0 =>
        DATA_IN <= "01010101";
        wait until CLK = '1';
        DATA_IN <= "00110011";
        wait until CLK = '1';
        -- Lots of pretty complex stimuli
        assert DATA_OUT = "00110011"
        report "Output mismatch!"
        severity failure;
      when 1 =>
        -- Lots of pretty complex stimuli
      -- when ... =>
      -- Plenty more instruction codes
      others =>
        null;
  end procedure DoComplexStuff;
end package body MyModuleAPI;
```

Therefore, MyModule_tb would include the package MyModuleAPI with a parameter specifying itself as the top level component and MyTopLevel_tb would include the same package with a parameter properly specifying the path to MyModule. (?)

**NOTE**: yes, my intention is to modify (bit-bang) internal signals during a top-level test. This would be similar to using ModelSim's "signal_force" and "signal_release" commands.

Thanks in advance for your guidance!

Comment: I've read your message three times, but is not clear to me what your actual question is. Could you please ask clear questions?

Comment: I think he wants to define an alias based on a generic. As far as I know, this is not possible.

Comment: @scary_jeff If that is the case, the aliases he makes make no sense: `CLK` etc are ports of the component, not signals. Also, it seems like he wants to instantiate a component inside a package... although the actual instantiation is missing. He should probably put the ports he wants to modify in the parameter list of his procedure..... Actually, he should really explain why he wants the procedure available at the top level.

Comment: @JHBonarius I require the procedure available at the top level because simulating the entire communication chain takes about 80 hrs and it's become unfeasible. Therefore, the ability to "peek" and "write" into a component's signals values from the top level using aliases is extremely useful to reduce simulation time whilst not significantly sacrificing coverage.
Regarding the "ports" comment, my intention is to force signals to a specific value during simulation, thereby overriding the input values.
@ scary_jeff dang... I was hoping there was a way of doing this :/

Comment: Setting the ports/signals a different value will not work as you write. It will just act as a second driver and resolve to `'X'`. You will need to `force` and `release` using VHDL-2008. See [this](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_small/). And what you want is probably possible with a different approach. It just requires deep insight in your design. Not something for StackOverflow.